# symfony2 mysql ranking based on time interval

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

i'm working on symfony2 project and i have to write a query that show ranked users based on number of views of their reviews on differnets periods (weekly, monthly and all time)

so i have this structure :

```
user table (user)   review table (review)
+---+--------+      +---+--------+------+-----+
|id |username|      |id |user_id |title |desc |
+------------+      +------------+------+-----+
|5  | mark   |      |1  | 5      |  tt  | aaa | 
|6  | steve  |      |2  | 7      |  tt  | aaa |
|7  | user   |      |3  | 6      |  tt  | aaa |
+---+--------+      +---+--------+------+-----+

review log view table (review_view)
+----------+--------+---------------------+
|review_id |user_id |viewed_at            |
+----------+--------+---------------------+
|1         | 1      | 2014-06-05 15:12:00 | 
|2         | 2      | 2014-06-05 15:12:00 |
|3         | 8      | 2014-06-05 16:12:00 |
|1         | 1      | 2014-06-05 15:12:00 | 
|2         | 2      | 2014-06-07 20:12:00 |
|3         | 10     | 2014-06-07 15:12:00 |
|1         | null   | 2014-06-07 15:12:00 | 
|2         | 2      | 2014-06-09 15:12:00 |
|3         | 3      | 2014-06-09 15:12:00 |
|1         | 1      | 2014-06-09 15:12:00 | 
|2         | 20     | 2014-06-09 15:12:00 |
|3         | 8      | 2014-06-03 15:12:00 |
+---+--------+------+---------------------+
```

the review_view table log every time user(user_id) view a review (review_id) the user_id can be null for users not logged in

the problem is i have to display them like showed in the following picture

[image: ranked users]

description of the picture: 
- the weekly,monthly and all time are tabs
- the red arrows is to say if the ranking has changed from last week

So any idea to do it with symfony2 or mysql ?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use `case` and `group by` to get the values for each user for the last two time periods.  this will certainly produce a select statement that can't be written easily in Doctrine, you might be able to do it with DQL.

Another choice would be to write a view in MySQL and then use that as if it was a table in your Symfony program.  Views used to have terrible performance in MySQL, but that may have improved.